# Having to write source ~/.zshrc and source ~/.zsh_profile to run flutter commands and cannot create flutter project

Tags: flutter

This is my flutter doctor summary

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.9, on macOS 14.3.1 23D60 darwin-arm64, locale
 en-CA)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.2)
    ✗ CocoaPods not installed.
        CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin
        code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
        Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
        For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
      To install see
      https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for
      instructions.
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2023.3.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.86.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] Network resources

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Without sourcing both the zsh files this is what I get when I type flutter doctor /Users/Jim/Desktop/flutter/bin/flutter: line 40: dirname: command not found /Users/Jim/Desktop/flutter/bin/flutter: line 40: cd: : No such file or directory /Users/Jim/Desktop/flutter/bin/flutter: line 41: basename: command not found /Users/Jim/Desktop/flutter/bin/flutter: line 54: uname: command not found

I am also using android studio code but I can't start a project because it says "Flutter SDK is not found in the specified location" even though that is the correct SDK path.

This is my zsh_profile

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

This is my zshrc

```
export PATH=~/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:$PATH
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/Jim/Desktop/flutter/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/Jim/Development/Android/sdk/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/Jim/Development/Android/sdk/cmdline-tools/bin
```

I am on MAC OS Sonoma. I am very new to terminal and figuring out paths and other related things. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `PATH` is already given an initial definition and exported in `/etc/zprofile`; there's should be no reason for your personal `.zprofile`(?) to redefine it.

Comment: `.zsh_profile` should be named `.zprofile` in order for it to be sourced automatically when starting a login shell. `.zshrc` should not be modifying the environment at all; put environment variables in `.zprofile` and let `.zshrc` focus on settings specific to interactive shells.

Comment: You *overwrote* the existing value of `PATH` in that file, rather than adding `.../flutter/bin` to the existing value.

Answer (score 0):

You said

> `.zprofile` already exists though. I currently have this in there:
>
> ```
> eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
> export PATH=/Users/satadsharar/Desktop/flutter/bin
> ```

Note that you *replaced* the existing value of `PATH` with a single directory, rather than *adding* a directory. You forgot to put `$PATH` in the new value. (You don't need to use `export`; if nothing else does, the `eval` command executes an `export PATH=...` command emitted by `shellenv`, so `PATH` is guaranteed to be exported already. Even that is overly cautious, as `PATH` is typically exported very early in shell startup; the default `/etc/zprofile` does as well.)

Your `.zprofile` should look more like this:

```
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
PATH=/Users/satadsharar/Desktop/flutter/bin:$PATH
# Remove the lines from .zshrc and add some of them here instead.     
PATH=/Users/satadsharar/Development/Android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH
PATH=/Users/satadsharar/Development/Android/sdk/cmdline-tools/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Is VSCode starting a a login instance of zsh?

Comment: I just checked and it was running bash. I changed it to zsh. I tried creating a project again and noticed the same error as above but on the side a notification pops up saying Flutter Daemon failed to start source: Dart